# Сжатие картинки

Tags: php, изображения

Здравствуйте. Подскажите, пожалуйста. Столкнулась с вот такой проблемой: нужно сделать маленькую копию картинки, но не могу узнать расширение файла. Вот код сжатия:

```
list($width, $height) = getimagesize($fileName);
$new_width  = 200;
$new_height = 160;

if(strstr($fileName, '.png') || strstr($fileName, '.PNG'))
    {
    $image = imagecreatefrompng($fileName);
    }
else if(strstr($fileName, '.jpg') || strstr($fileName, '.JPG') || strstr($fileName, '.jpeg') || strstr($fileName, '.JPEG'))
    {
    $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($fileName);
    }
else if(strstr($fileName, '.gif') || strstr($fileName, '.GIF'))
    {
    $image = imagecreatefromgif($fileName);
    }

$image_p = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height) or die('Cannot initialize new GD image stream.');
imagecopyresampled($image_p, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $width, $height);

function addThumb($fileName)
    {
    $fileName    = array_reverse(explode('.', $fileName));
    $fileName[0] = 'smpgthumb.'.$fileName[0];
    $fileName    = implode('.', array_reverse($fileName));
    return $fileName;
    }
```

Вроде бы все должно работать но переменная `$fileName` имеет значения вида `my_photo.jpeg` или `my_photo.gif` и тд и тп .... как можно сжать в этом случае?
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: @eicto, +1 перенесите в ответ

Answer (score 3):

```
// Недавно нашёл в интернете, очень хороший класс
<?php

class SimpleImage {

   var $image;
   var $image_type;

   function load($filename) {
      $image_info = getimagesize($filename);
      $this->image_type = $image_info[2];
      if( $this->image_type == IMAGETYPE_JPEG ) {
         $this->image = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
      } elseif( $this->image_type == IMAGETYPE_GIF ) {
         $this->image = imagecreatefromgif($filename);
      } elseif( $this->image_type == IMAGETYPE_PNG ) {
         $this->image = imagecreatefrompng($filename);
      }
   }
   function save($filename, $image_type=IMAGETYPE_JPEG, $compression=75, $permissions=null) {
      if( $image_type == IMAGETYPE_JPEG ) {
         imagejpeg($this->image,$filename,$compression);
      } elseif( $image_type == IMAGETYPE_GIF ) {
         imagegif($this->image,$filename);
      } elseif( $image_type == IMAGETYPE_PNG ) {
         imagepng($this->image,$filename);
      }
      if( $permissions != null) {
         chmod($filename,$permissions);
      }
   }
   function output($image_type=IMAGETYPE_JPEG) {
      if( $image_type == IMAGETYPE_JPEG ) {
         imagejpeg($this->image);
      } elseif( $image_type == IMAGETYPE_GIF ) {
         imagegif($this->image);
      } elseif( $image_type == IMAGETYPE_PNG ) {
         imagepng($this->image);
      }
   }
   function getWidth() {
      return imagesx($this->image);
   }
   function getHeight() {
      return imagesy($this->image);
   }
   function resizeToHeight($height) {
      $ratio = $height / $this->getHeight();
      $width = $this->getWidth() * $ratio;
      $this->resize($width,$height);
   }
   function resizeToWidth($width) {
      $ratio = $width / $this->getWidth();
      $height = $this->getheight() * $ratio;
      $this->resize($width,$height);
   }
   function scale($scale) {
      $width = $this->getWidth() * $scale/100;
      $height = $this->getheight() * $scale/100;
      $this->resize($width,$height);
   }
   function resize($width,$height) {
      $new_image = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
      imagecopyresampled($new_image, $this->image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $this->getWidth(), $this->getHeight());
      $this->image = $new_image;
   }
}
?>

// Вызываем класс
$image = new SimpleImage();
$image->load("Сдесь сама фотка фотка");
   $image->resizeToWidth(70); // В аргумент ширину картинки, которая нужна(Она пропорц. уменьш.)
   $image->save("Путь сохранение"); // Сохраняем
```

Answer (score 2):

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreate.php#81831 - один из корректных методов получения типа картинки. а строку расширения можно получить:

```
$extension=pathinfo($filename)['extension'];
```

Comment: А этот скрипт не подскажите как переделать что бы он сжимал ?!

Answer (score 0):

```
$a=end(explode(".", "$filename"));
```